# NullPointerException not occurring within try/catch

Tags: apex, exception, bug

I'm writing a testMethod for a custom Exception class.

As part of the testMethod I want to deliberately throw another exception to become the inner cause of my custom exception.

E.g.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public Id opportunityId {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public CustomException(Id exceptionOpportuntiyId, string message, Exception innerException) {
        this.opportunityId = exceptionOpportuntiyId;
        this.setMessage(message);
        this.initCause(innerException);
    }
}
```

And the corresponding testMethod:

```
private static testMethod void customExceptionTest() {
    Id opportuntiyId = '006000000000000';
    try {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try {

            integer foo = null;
            // Intentional NullPointerException
            foo = foo + 1;
            System.assert(false, 'Null Exception Expected');
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            throw new CustomException(opportuntiyId, 'customExceptionTest', ex);
        }
        System.assert(false, 'CustomException Expected');
    } catch (CustomException saveEx) {
        System.assertEquals(opportuntiyId, saveEx.opportunityId);
        System.assertEquals('customExceptionTest', saveEx.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Oddly, the assertion in the inner try block is causing the test method to fail. The line `foo = foo + 1` executed without throwing an exception!

This seemed odd, so I tried simplifying.

---

The following produces the expected NullPointerException when run as anonymous apex:

```
integer foo = null;
foo = foo + 1;
```

> 12:38:48:016 FATAL_ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

---

The wrapping the same code in a try/catch block:

```
try {
    integer foo = null;
    foo = foo + 1;
    System.debug('foo: ' + foo);
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
  System.debug('Exception');
}
```

> 12:42:28:013 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|foo: null

The expected NullPointerException didn't occur. Instead `foo` is null!

---

I've raised with support (Case #08416231), but is anyone else aware of this or can confirm it is occurring for them as well?

Ideally I'd like a known issue reference or existing case number.

Comment: I get the same, most odd. 

However do this and it works... 

integer foo = null;
try {
    foo = foo + 1;
    System.debug('foo: ' + foo);
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
  System.debug('Exception');
}

Comment: @AndrewFawcett, Thanks for confirming. I'll use your suggestion to get the test case passing. Still, I find this kind of bug concerning. :)

Comment: re: concerning, agree. Do let us know what comes of your support case if you can.

Comment: Will do, might take some time. I'm still waiting for a resolution to the case I raised 15 days ago for the other [NullPointerException issue I had](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/incorrect-line-reference-from-nullpointerexception).

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Support responded today that they have confirmed the issue and will be working on a fix. No ETA or known issue reference number yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same and also agree it looks like an Apex runtime bug. Perhaps relating to scope, as moving the variable declaration and init out of the try scope works...

```
Integer foo = null;
try {
    foo = foo + 1;
    System.debug('foo: ' + foo);
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
  System.debug('Exception');
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. In my test case I went with `integer foo = (integer)null + 1;`. Moving the `foo` deceleration didn't work there (I suspect due to the two levels of try/catch).