# How can that code ever produce a NullReference in the last line?

Tags: apex

I am getting a `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` in the last line (the one with the return) of the following code.

```
  ...
  AggregateResult result = getResult(...);
  Decimal value = (Decimal) result.get(fieldName);
  return (value == null) ? 0 : value;
}
```

This really sounds strange to me as I added this line to prevent Nullreference errors.
As this code is - let me called it - hard to debug I need to analyse this in my head and not in the IDE ;)

I can only think of 3 error sources that would throw other errors:

1. `AggregateResult result` is null -> Would throw an error in the line above.
2. fieldName does not exist on on `result` -> Would also throw an error in the line above
3. Value can not be casted into a `Decimal` -> Would show different Exception

Might this be be a side effect of code in the `return` statement?!

Comment: I suspect it may be an order of operations thing in the return statement. What if you assign the ternary operator to a temp variable and return that instead?

Comment: What is the type of the field you're getting when the error occurs?

Comment: The same as in the 99% non failing jobs - Decimal.

Comment: I've seen the exception line numbers [be off by one line previously](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/incorrect-line-reference-from-nullpointerexception). If this is the case here I'd suspect the `result` is causing the null exception. Try setting the Apex code logging to Finest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen the exception line numbers be off by one line previously - see [Incorrect line reference from NullPointerException](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/incorrect-line-reference-from-nullpointerexception).

If this is the case here I'd suspect the **`result`** in `(Decimal) result.get(fieldName)` is causing the null exception and the NullPointerException is incorrectly indicating the following line.

Oddly enough, when I last encountered this, Salesforce support suggested setting the Apex code logging to Finest. Somehow this corrects the line number reference. It's a good head scratcher on how the exception handling is dependant on the logging!

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting the ternary into an if-else statement to debug it:

```
  ...
  AggregateResult result = getResult(...);
  Decimal value = (Decimal) result.get(fieldName);

  system.debug(value);

  if(value == null) { 
    return 0; 
  }
  else { 
    return value; 
  }
}
```

That would at least give you different line numbers for the error, and it may help you pinpoint why it is occurring. If you find out what it is, you can always change it back.

Comment: "...As this code is - let me called it - hard to debug I need to analyse this in my head and not in the IDE ;)..."